# My OnPress does not link to a screen i have made - React Native

Tags: react-native, navigation

I've got 3 screens in a Drawer Navigation and 1 screen in a stack Navigation.

app.js

```
const Stack = createStackNavigator();
function Navigator() {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator>
      <Stack.Screen name="Spelare" component={PlayersScreen} />
      <Stack.Screen name="Details" component={DetailsScreen} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
}
const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();
export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Drawer.Navigator
        initialRouteName="Hem"
        drawerPosition="right"
        drawerType="slide">
        <Drawer.Screen
          name="Hem"
          component={HomeScreen}
          style={styles.drawerItem}
        />
        <Drawer.Screen
          name="Kontakt"
          style={{ color: 'red' }}
          component={ContactScreen}
        />
   
        <Drawer.Screen
          name="Spelare"
          style={{ color: 'red' }}
          component={PlayersScreen}
        />
      </Drawer.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
   
  );
};


function StackNavigator() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
    <Drawer.Navigator
      initialRouteName="Hem"
      drawerPosition="right"
      drawerType="slide">
      <Drawer.Screen
        name="Hem"
        component={HomeScreen}
        style={styles.drawerItem}
      />
      <Drawer.Screen
        name="Kontakt"
        style={{ color: 'red' }}
        component={ContactScreen}
      />
      {/* Look down ... */}
      <Drawer.Screen
        name="Details"
        style={{ color: 'red' }}
        component={DetailsScreen}
      />
    </Drawer.Navigator>
  </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

On the PlayersScreen i've got a FlatList rendering names and when clicking on a name i want it to take the user to Details Screen and load only that person. This all worked when having the DetailsScreen in the Drawer navigator but i don't want that showing in the Drawer menu in the App.

FlatList, Inside playerScreen which is also in the App.js file

```
<FlatList
            data={data}
            keyExtractor={item => item.Name}
            renderItem={({ item }) => (
      <View style={{alignItems: 'center', backgroundColor: '#25D495',  borderRadius: 15, fontFamily: 'Roboto, sans-serif', marginBottom: 15, height: 40}}>
          <Text 
            style={styles.listStyle} onPress={() => {navigation.navigate('Details', {itemId: item._id})}}>{item.Name}
          </Text>
      </View>
            )}
          />
```

**I get the following ERROR : The action 'NAVIGATE' was not handled by any Navigator, do you have a screen named Details?**

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: But your `Stack` is not rendered inside your navigatio tree ... I mean inside your `Navigationcontainer`

Comment: But i can't just copy in the Stack.Navigator inside t he NavigationContainer, right?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you replace `Spelare` screen in your `drawer` with a `StackNavigator` like so..

**First**
Create a stack having both `PlayersScreen`, and `DetailsScreen`

```
  const Stack = createStackNavigator();
  function StackNavigator() {
    return (
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen name="Spelare" component={PlayersScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Details" component={DetailsScreen} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    );
  }
```

**Second**
Replace your `PlayersScreen` in your Main drawer navigator with your created `Stack`

```
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Drawer.Navigator
        initialRouteName="Hem"
        drawerPosition="right"
        drawerType="slide">
        <Drawer.Screen
          name="Hem"
          component={HomeScreen}
          style={styles.drawerItem}
        />
        <Drawer.Screen
          name="Kontakt"
          style={{ color: 'red' }}
          component={ContactScreen}
        />
        {/* Look down ... */}
        <Drawer.Screen
          name="SpelareStack"
          style={{ color: 'red' }}
          component={Stack}
        />
      </Drawer.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
```

Comment: I have tried this and this sitll gives me the same error, it's asking if i have a screen named Details, updating the thread so you can see what i've done.

Comment: Could you update your question with that update you did ...

Comment: @Niqqo That's not the suggested solution :) ... take a second look at the answer...